# cannot connect mysql with nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am absolutely new to node.js. while Iam trying to connect mysql with node.js I got this. Really looking for a help.

> { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8889
>     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
>    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1045:20)
>
> ### at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1087:14)
>
> at Protocol._enqueue (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/htbf/nodejsdb/mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:141:48)
>       at Protocol.handshake (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/htbf/nodejsdb/mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:41)
>       at Connection.connect (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/htbf/nodejsdb/mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:130:18)
>       at Connection._implyConnect (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/htbf/nodejsdb/mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:461:10)
>       at Connection.query (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/htbf/nodejsdb/mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:206:8)
>       at Object. (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/htbf/nodejsdb/mysql/app1.js:11:12)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
>     errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
>     syscall: 'connect',
>     address: '127.0.0.1',
>     port: 8889,
>     fatal: true }
>
> my code is
>       var mysql = require('mysql');

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host: 'localhost',
port: '8889',
user: 'root',
password: 'root',
socket: '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
database: 'login_db'
});
connection.query('SELECT * from test_table',function(err,rows,feilds){
if(!err){
    console.log(rows);
} else{
    console.log(err);
}
});
connection.end();
```

Comment: You should show your connection code.  That said, it looks like either MySQL isn't running, or it's not running on port 3306, or you have a host firewall / antivirus that's blocking local connections on that port.

Comment: @paul MAMP's default mysql port is 8889. This is the error you get when you don't turn on MAMP. Turn it on bro! Then try again.

Comment: @Paul Thanks for your immediate reply. now I inserted the connection code and latest error!.

Comment: @Sathiya Anbu If you are connecting via a `port`, why do you specify a `socket`? Try choosing one of them and make sure MySQL also uses that method.

Comment: CALL `connection.connect()` before you try your query.

Comment: @magreenberg that's called implicitly by `connection.query` according to the docs. Also, the error indicates that the connection is being attempted.

Comment: @magreenberg I tried without query it shows the same error

Comment: @abcdn I tried with port and socket separately but no changed same error occur.

Comment: Could anyone explain what the error mean?

Comment: @paul I turn off the firewall to allow all the connection but same error :(

Comment: @SathiyaAnbu are you able to connect to mysql from the terminal `mysql --port=8889 --user=root --password=root`?

Comment: Thanks for all your replies. I solved the problem by change the bind-address as 0.0.0.0 in my.cnf file .